# Replace a sequence which matches sublist with no order

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider I have the following list with no duplicates. I would like to replace `{a,c}` with a number.

```
lst = {a,b,c,d}
```

Result I want is `{1, b, d}`. This can be in any order.

---

I have tried the following using `SequenceReplace[]` which works only if the sequence I want to replace is in the same order as in `lst`.

```
SequenceReplace[{a, b, c, d}, {b, c} -> 1]
```

> {a,1,d}

```
SequenceReplace[{a, b, c, d}, {a, c} -> 1]
```

> {a,b,c,d}

Is there a way to get `{1, b, d}`?

Comment: Do you have more than one occurrence of `a, ... , c, ...` in your input list? If so then please update the question with more test cases.

Comment: You cold replace a with 1 and c with Nothing: `lst /. {a -> 1, c -> Nothing}`

Comment: @Syed the list doesn't have any duplicates. I have updated the question

Comment: @DanielHuber That's a good solution. Thank you. It works for me.

Comment: If you do require to work with non-adjacent sequence items, here is a possible solution: `SequenceReplace[lst, {g___, a, x___, c, y___} :> 
  Sequence[g, 1, x, y]]`

Comment: or just `SequenceReplace[lst, {a, x___, c} -> Sequence[1, x]]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use [`OrderlessPatternSequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderlessPatternSequence.html).

With

```
lst = Permutations[{a, b, c, d}]
```

> ```
> {{a,b,c,d},{a,b,d,c},{a,c,b,d},{a,c,d,b},{a,d,b,c},{a,d,c,b}
> ,{b,a,c,d},{b,a,d,c},{b,c,a,d},{b,c,d,a},{b,d,a,c},{b,d,c,a}
> ,{c,a,b,d},{c,a,d,b},{c,b,a,d},{c,b,d,a},{c,d,a,b},{c,d,b,a}
> ,{d,a,b,c},{d,a,c,b},{d,b,a,c},{d,b,c,a},{d,c,a,b},{d,c,b,a}}
> ```

Then

```
lst /. {OrderlessPatternSequence[a, c, e___]} :> {1, e}
```

> ```
> {{1,b,d},{1,b,d},{1,b,d},{1,b,d},{1,b,d},{1,b,d}
> ,{1,b,d},{1,b,d},{1,b,d},{1,b,d},{1,b,d},{1,b,d}
> ,{1,b,d},{1,b,d},{1,b,d},{1,b,d},{1,b,d},{1,b,d}
> ,{1,b,d},{1,b,d},{1,b,d},{1,b,d},{1,b,d},{1,b,d}}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since the pattern is orderless you don't need separate s,m,e. Just `lst /. {OrderlessPatternSequence[a, c, x___]} :> {1, x}`

Comment: @SimonWoods  Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 5):

```
$Version

(* "13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

rules[lst_, target_, value_] := 
 Flatten[{#[[1]] :> value, Thread[Rest[#] :> Nothing]}] &@
  Select[lst, MemberQ[target, #] &]

lst = {a, b, c, d};

target = {a, c};

lst /. rules[lst, target, 1]

(* {1, b, d} )
```

For a more complicated example

```
SeedRandom[1234];

lst = RandomSample[{a, b, c, d, e, f}]

(* {a, f, d, b, e, c} *)

target = {c, a, f};

lst /. rules[lst, target, 1]

(* {1, d, b, e} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {a, b, c, d};

f = SequenceReplace[list, {OrderlessPatternSequence[#1, #2, x_]} :> Sequence[1, x]] &;

f @@@ {{a, c}, {b, d}, {a, b}}
```

> {{1, b, d}, {a, 1, c}, {1, c, d}}

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = {a, b, c, d};
```

---

Using `MapAt` and `DeleteElements`:

```
rules[lst_, target_, value_] := 
Reverse@DeleteElements[Reverse@MapAt[value &, lst, 
Position[lst, Alternatives @@ target]], {value} -> {value}]

rules[lst, #, 1] & /@ {{a, c}, {b, d}, {a, b}}
```

> `{{1, b, d}, {a, 1, c}, {1, c, d}}`

Answer (score 1):

A basic approach:

```
func[s_, t_] := 
 If[Intersection[s, t] == Sort[t], 
  Join[SymmetricDifference[s, t], {1}], s]
```

For example:

```
w = {a, b, c, d};
func[w, {a, c}]
```

yields {b, d, 1}

Or @BobHanlon example:

```
SeedRandom[1234];
lst = RandomSample[{a, b, c, d, e, f}]
func[lst, {c, a, f}]
```

yields: {b, d, e, 1}